# Setting up PyQt4 for win7

Tags: python, windows, installation, pyqt4

This is dumb, but I've just installed python and PyQt4 on my win7 laptop. However, when I try to import PyQt4, python can't find that module.

I followed the directions here:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-win.html

I've set up the Path environment variable. I ran the configure but my lib dir is still empty. I'm just not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install PyQt4, not Qt4.

http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download